# How can i pass a list as argument for a function element by element in Elixir?

Tags: list, function, enums, arguments, elixir

i have a function (`lex_raw_tokens`) that receives 2 arguments. Another function has 2 lists of elements that i need to pass as arguments to the other function, but element by element.

In the original code the function only received 1 argument and i called it using `Enum.flat_map(sal, &lex_raw_tokens/1)`, sal being the list i'm passing. This worked but later on i had to change lex_raw_tokens to receive 2 arguments instead of 1.

I tried solving the issue with `Enum.flat_map(sal, &lex_raw_tokens(&1, line))` and, while this technically works, line gets passed as an entire list instead of individual elements.

I'm still quite new to Elixir and i haven't found any other function to replace `flat_map` that does what i want and i haven't found a way to use `flat_map` like this.

I should also mention that the lists i'm passing have a variable lenght so i can't brute force my way around this problem. Also, both lists have the same lenght and have a relation, so I would need to use the first element of `sal` with the first element of `line`, the second with the second and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Enum.zip/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#zip/2) is your friend here.

```rb
sal = ~w|one two three|
line = ~w|apple orange lemon|

sal
|> Enum.zip(line)
|> Enum.flat_map(&lex_raw_tokens(elem(&1, 0), elem(&1, 1)))
```